# Unit Test for Timespan with Javascript

Tags: javascript, testing

I would like to write a Unit Test for my Timespan.
I got some more lines of Code for Week,Year,Quartal.
But if i know how to Test "Today and Yesterday, i could use them for the others too.
Hope someone can help me :)

```
const firstSelectionOptions = {
  [Timespan.Day]: [
    { value: FirstSelection.Current, name: 'Today' },
    { value: FirstSelection.Previous, name: 'Yesterday' },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it :)

```
describe('FirstSelection', () => {
it('should have a day "today/yesterday"', () => {
    expect(getFirstSelectionOptions(Timespan.Day)).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([
      expect.objectContaining({name: 'Today'}),
      expect.objectContaining({name: 'Yesterday'})
    ])
    )
  });
```